# Is there a way to specify the application icon for a ClickOnce application manifest using Mage/MageUI?

Tags: c#, clickonce, icons

I need a way to specify an application icon for a ClickOnce deployment. Basically this will be the icon shown for the application shortcut in the Start Menu - Program Files, also during the installation of the application.
I can do this from the Visual Studio IDE (by specifying the application icon in the application tab of the project properties).

But I can not figure out a way to do this using [Mage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acz3y3te%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)/MageUI. Is there way to do this using Mage/MageUI?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152188/can-i-create-a-desktop-icon-for-a-clickonce-application

Comment: I disagree; that is not a duplicate; one relates to the manifest, one is a desktop icon - entirely different

Comment: (if that is now complete, you might want to click the green "tick"...)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At the command line, from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/c8360ca5-f920-4ecb-8a85-b8f478e2a16f/) - e.g.

```
mage -New Application -ToFile MyApplication.exe.manifest -Name "My Application" -Version 1.0.0.0 -FromDirectory bin -IconFile ApplicationIcon.ico
```

In MageUI, from [here](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/dotnet/after-three-years-i-discover-how-to-choose-a-clickonce-icon-in-mageui/) - set the icon's File Type to Icon File on the Files list.

Comment: Thanks Marc. This helped.
Sorry for the delayed response.

Comment: The docs say to use a full path but that's impossible if the clickonce is an office addin, it puts your directory at a pretty obfuscated looking path.