# Desktop shortcut for ClickOnce deployed application

Tags: vb.net, deployment, clickonce

I would like to create a desktop shortcut for my [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) deployed application. The [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) is [Visual Studio 2005](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2005) and there isn't any need for upgrading to Visual Studio 2008 yet.

Comment: If you have to stay with Visual Studio 2005, your only option is to write code to create the icon. Here's [how to do it][1]. However, be aware of the fact that if a user uninstalls your application, the desktop icon won't get removed. If you ever upgrade to Visual Studio 2008 SP1, you'll get this feature out of the box. [1]:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152188/can-i-create-a-desktop-icon-for-a-clickonce-application

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in ClickOnce, and that is by design:

> One of the goals of ClickOnce was to make the user experience of installing and running rich client code as "web-like" as possible

[...]

> In keeping with the web-like model we
>   wanted to be as minimally invasive as
>   possible in terms of shell footprint
>   and opted to not "spam" the desktop
>   with shortcuts (note that on the XP
>   startmenu will light up with a
>   notification that an app has been
>   installed for ClickOnce apps).

as explained [in this thread on social.msdn.microsoft.com](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/6a15329e-df6f-44c3-a2e2-bc3bbb9ba16e).

The only workaround is to create the desktop icon yourself on first startup. But doing so is not recommended.

You might want to reevaluate whether your really need a desktop icon. I personally hate installers which do that.

Comment: what i don't get is the "by design". I guess in VS2008 they don't care about "web-like" since there is an option of creating a desktop shortcut

Comment: They've noticed that the web is very popular, but they still don't quite get why. That's why they've also put in stuff like error providers.