# Add A "Check for Updates" Option

Tags: c#, c++

I would like to know, how to check for updates for my own developed software. I mean when a user uses the program and clicks on check for updates, what should I do and how to download the new application? Is it parsing the website download page, or using a database?

I would like to know how to achieve this in both C++ and C#.

Comment: Posible dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/780594/how-can-i-make-my-c-application-check-for-updates

Comment: It seems somewhat unlikely that you'll find an existing library written for both C# and unmanaged C++.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite literally 100's of different ways of doing this.  So you need to put a little more thought into what your application platform/architecture is capable of (i.e. do you have net access, what is the technical level of your typical user etc).  As examples of a solutions:

At startup your app checks a webservice for the latest version number and then compares to the current install.  If the version is different then the user has an option to download and install the newer version.  This could be done by either getting the use to go to a specific web address or you could download and execute it for them.

You also have the option of using something called Clickonce, this will effectively handle all this for you.  This is a big subject so Google is your friend on this one, but as a starter have a look at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28VS.80%29.aspx