# Easy update assistance

Tags: c#

We are writing simple architectured software in **C# 3.5**.
What I was searching for is for easy updating framework/application...

We don't have COM components, Servicdes to install or whatever, so basically what we need is *xcopy* stuff form one Server side directory to the client. So what the program should do is **like a workflow**:

1. Check some location \Server\Updates for manifest.xml
2. Check the local setup verison
3. Download all available DLLs (doesn't necessary all need for complete application, so kind of *patch* stuff) and substitude them with *"old"* ones.

I'm aware of *ClickOnce*, of *App publishing*, also our *setup generator supports autoamtic updates* (even if noone yet used it, and I don't want to use to not strongly couple ourselfs with that technology).

Do you know some app or technology, that I'm not aware (actually listed in question) which could better fit our needs. ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: See this SO post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/780594/how-can-i-make-my-c-application-check-for-updates. I tried wyBuild, it worked fine.

Comment: can post like an aswer , easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after the comment, the answer:

I would look at this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780594/how-can-i-make-my-c-application-check-for-updates).

I looked [wyWuild](http://wyday.com/wybuild/) and the AutomaticUpdater controler some time ago. It really looked great.

**EDIT**

I just remembered that I chose to use [AppLife Update](http://www.kineticjump.com/Update/Default.aspx) in the end. It's more expensive but the features are extremely good