# Write upgradeable Software in C#, and its upgrades

Tags: c#

**How can I write a software so that it can be updateable?** By updateable I mean that the 
software I create can be updated whenever it's necessary.

**How do I write those updates?** I understand that depending on the way you decide to make the updateable software, probably there will be different ways of writing the updates. If you tell me at least one way to do it, then maybe I can think of other ways.

PS: Sorry for any english mistakes and for bothering so much with my questions, but I've only been writing software for 1 month, so as you can see I'm not used to this kind of thinking. I'm learning though.

Comment: This is a big topic.  You will usually have better luck asking for focused questions.  That said, what technologies are you trying to deploy (e.g. WinForms, WPF, ASPX, Silverlight)

Comment: A possible solution is ClickOnce.

Comment: Are you strong signing your assemblies?  Can you load your DLLs dynamically?  Or do you want some type of scripting ability?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make my C# application check for updates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/780594/how-can-i-make-my-c-sharp-application-check-for-updates)

Comment: I want to learn how to do it for WinForms and WPF. I thought I might've been a big topic. Then maybe could you point me to someplace where I might get an idea? About ClickOnce, I'll look into it, I can't say anything more than that because it's the first time I'm reading about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look into [ClickOnce deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), which is a method for deploying applications and updates.